# How do I make part of my table caption in italic font?

Tags: tables, formatting, captions

I am very new to Latex and I am trying to make a very simple table with a species name in the title (caption). I want all of my title to be normal font except for the species name, which should be italic. Here is my (truncated) `longtable` code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{rrllr}

\caption*{Table 4: De Novo SNPs Identified in Lab-Adapted C. remanei}\\

  \hline

 & bp & ref & alt & af \\ 

  \hline

1 & 1077553 & A & G & 0.002184 \\ 

  2 & 3402873 & C & A & 0.002342 \\ 

   \hline

\caption*{Table S1: SNPs present in the rare E. coli W3110 spike-in strain }

\label{table:1}

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

...Is there a simple way to do this?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question is a little bit unclear

Answer (score 4):

Simply use the `\textit{}` tag.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{rrllr}

\caption*{Table 4: De Novo SNPs Identified in Lab-Adapted \textit{C. remanei}}\\

  \hline

 & bp & ref & alt & af \\ 

  \hline

1 & 1077553 & A & G & 0.002184 \\ 

  2 & 3402873 & C & A & 0.002342 \\ 

   \hline

\caption*{Table S1: SNPs present in the rare \textit{E. coli} W3110 spike-in strain }

\label{table:1}

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

This will yield the following:

[image: output]

Comment: Quicker than me ;-) Perhaps it's a good idea to show a screen shot

Comment: Good idea! Done & done.

Answer (score 3):

i'd suggest using `\emph{...}`, which will switch back and forth between
italic and upright depending on the context.  although italic is suitable
here, in an italic context, this term would "disappear" into the background.
some reputable publications set photo captions in italic as a matter of
course, and there, species names are set upright for contrast.

actually, i would handle this indirectly, by defining a specific command:

```
\newcommand{\spp}[1]{\emph{#1}}
```

not only would this allow changes to the style globally, but would make it
possible to easily identify all instances of species names in the document.